# Youtube played seconds count

Tags: javascript, youtube, listener, detect

How can i get the count of played seconds of embedded youtube video?

exclude the count when video is paused/not started/skipped/ buffering
only the played seconds, how to detect them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use current time

```
 ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
 ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Is this what you were looking for?